# Overwrite column results with if statement in mysql

Tags: mysql

I guess I'm just being lazy but if I run the sql query:

```
   SELECT *, IF(enddate='0000-00-00',null,enddate) as enddate from
   employees where (enddate is null || enddate > now())
   order by name asc
```

I obviously end up with two `enddate` columns.

I was just wondering if there is anyway to overwrite the `endate` column selected by `*` with the new one or do I have to replace the `*` with the individual columns?

Comment: I would suggest entering the fields you want in place of the `*`.

Comment: Also, you can use `NULLIF(enddate, '0000-00-00')` :-)

Comment: `SELECT *` is generally a pretty lazy approach to retrieving data from DB anyway, so just specify the fields you want.  Why I say it is lazy, is that, in many cases, you don't ever use every column in a table after retrieving data, so waste bandwidth, memory, etc. in retrieving this unused data, as opposed to simply specifying the fields.  I also find the specifying the fields make better long-term sense for code clarity.  You can look at your code a year down the line and understand exactly what data you are intending to work with.

Comment: I should also add that using `SELECT *` also could potentially expose your code to behavioral problems should there be a DB schema change.  For example, let's say in your case someone decided to add a new column to the `employees` table to, for instance, store some large text or blob data.  Maybe this DB schema change was made for a different script than the one you are concerned with.  Because you use `SELECT *` on this script, you will now be pulling is this additional data field that the script has no use for, degrading the performance of the script without you even touching it.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to avoid returning two columns. But - if you're using mysql-driver row fetch that uses associative fields returning (for example, PHP's [`mysqli_result::fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)), you can use the trick:

```
   SELECT 
     IF(enddate='0000-00-00',null,enddate) as enddate,  
     employees.* 
   from
     employees 
   where 
     (enddate is null || enddate > now())
   order by name asc
```

-don't forget to qualify full table name (i.e. `employees.*`, not just `*`). Sample can be found [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74f1e/9).

Then first field will be your expression and not original field. In fact, that is what you'll see in linked SQLFiddle example, i.e. it uses associative fields fetching, thus, one field overrides another, but that doesn't means that in original data set there will be one column (so in common case you *can not* rely on that - to check that you can, obviously, use `mysql` client)

In common case: only fully qualified fields sequence will do the stuff (so - yes, `*` can't be used)

Comment: it turned out that since I'm using php's pdo driver it appears to use the last occurrence of the column name, so the query i had worked as is, but this was a good solution nonetheless